# ¿Que función utilizo para crear una paginación dentro de un modal en Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, modal

Necesito crear una paginación en un formulario que tengo dentro de un modal en Bootstrap. Es decir un botón que ponga siguiente y sin recargar la pagina que pase a la siguiente parte del modal.

He probado con esto a `"class='modal' href='mi_modal.php&modal=".$i."` lo que hago con esto es recargar la pagina y con ello que se cierre la ventana de modal. Y no encuentro otra manera de hacerlo sin tener que recargar la pagina. Tendría que utilizar ajax? Porque lo he buscado con ajax y tampoco encuentro como hacer exactamente eso.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row margabajo ">
        <div style="flex">
            <img class="col-lg-1" src="./assets/images/chip-chap-twitter.png">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <h4 style="font-size: 30px;">Account</h4>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Full Name -->
        <label for="full_name_id" class="control-label"><h4>Full Name</h4></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="full_name" placeholder="John Deer">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Street 1 -->
        <label for="street1_id" class="control-label"><h4>Street Address 1</h4></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="street1" placeholder="Street address, P.O. box, company name, c/o">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Street 2 -->
        <label for="mail_id" class="control-label"><h4>Mail</h4></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="mail" placeholder="...@gmail.com / ...@hotmail.com / etc.">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> <!-- Country -->
        <label for="state_id" class="control-label"><h4>Country</h4></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="">

        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te voy a dar una idea. 1. Retorna desde el backend los trozos del formulario de acuerdo a un índice. 2. Al abrir el modal, obtén el primer trozo del formulario y agrégalo al cuerpo del formulario. 3. Ordena los trozos de manera horizontal, de manera que haya un *desborde* en el formulario que debes ocultar (`overflow: hidden`). 4. Cuando se haga click en el botón *siguiente*, se debe hacer una petición AJAX y obtener el siguiente trozo de formulario y a continuación deslizar la tira de trozos con una ligera transición via CSS. En caso se quiera retroceder, solo se desliza la tira al contrario.

Comment: Investiga cómo realizar los pasos que he escrito y, cuando tengas un código formado, vuelves a preguntar para que se te ayude en dudas puntuales y concretas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación, es una buena idea. Justo al rato de formular la pregunta consegui crearla añadiendo unas funciones en el .ts del modal, y creando una variable page number con un valor de 0 y que cada click en el boton llamara a la funcion next y sumara uno a la variable y asi llamando a la siguiente paguina la cual el valor era 1.   AQUI LAS FUNCIONES DEL TS----------                                                                                next() {
        this.pagenumber++
    }

    back() {
        this.pagenumber--
    }

Comment: y a cada div (cada uno de ellos era una pagina del modal)  le daba este valor <div *ngIf="pagenumber == 0"..> / <div *ngIf="pagenumber == 1"...> / <div *ngIf="pagenumber == 2"...> /etc    ------------------- asi cada vez que sumaba uno me cargaba la pagenumber con un valor de mas. Funciona bastante bien. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que insertaste ¿Que es exactamente? , no veo ninguna relación con lo que solicitas.

Pero quiero suponer que tu archivo en php acepta constantemente los parametros en GET, pondre un ejemplo sencillo de como lo puedes trabajar con Jquery y con el método "**post**" de jquery y tener todo de manera individual.

**parte de la vista  "index.php"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<!-- contenido dinámico AJAX -->
        <div>
            <h5>Contenido ajax</h5>
                <div id="response">
                    <h5>Selecciona un número</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="1" class="loadInfo" > 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="2" class="loadInfo" > 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="3" class="loadInfo" > 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="4" class="loadInfo" > 4 </a></li>
            <li><a href="5" class="loadInfo" > 5 </a></li>
        </ul>      
<!-- -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $(".loadInfo").click(function(){
            var number = $(this).attr("href");
            $.post( "postparams.php", { number: number }).done(function( data ) {
                $("#response").html(data);
              });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**archivo que recibe los parametros de tus links "postparams.php"**

```
<?php
    //Basicamente aqui imprimes solo el resultado de tu consulta
    $number = "";
    if(isset($_POST["number"])){
        $number = $_POST["number"];
        echo "<h5>Se ha impreso el valor ".$number ."</h5>";
    }
    else{

        echo "No se ha recibido nada";
    }

?>
```

(Solo copia y pega esto en 2 archivos distintos que esten en la misma carpeta)
Con esto debería entenderse como funciona una paginación basica, espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos!